# What should be the action in the case of a questions problem not existing?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

In the instance of this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32762672/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-the-key-of-the-1st-level

It appears that the issue raised in the question does not exist. What action (if any) should be taken when finding questions such as this?

Comment: there is an off-topic "not reproducible". I'd use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you reach a [certain reputation, you can vote to close a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes). There are one, possibly two, appropriate close reasons

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

or

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

The question linked already has a close vote with one of these.

Comment: And any user with at least [15 rep can still flag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) these questions for closure with the same reasons.  (It takes 50 rep for duplicate flagging because of the auto-comment).